# Functions as Conditions and Typeof Reference

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 1;
if (function f(){}) {
    x += typeof f;
}
x; //"1number"
```

Typeof f has to be a function which gets appended to x and the value should be "1function" how is typeof f a number?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KfrVg/ what do you have here? 1number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get `"1undefined"`, maybe you have another variable `f` which is a number.

The name (or identifier) of a *function expression* is only accessible inside the function itself. Your code does not create a public symbol `f`.

From the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13):

> The Identifier in a *FunctionExpression* can be referenced from inside the *FunctionExpression's FunctionBody* to allow the function to call itself recursively. However, unlike in a *FunctionDeclaration*, the *Identifier* in a *FunctionExpression* cannot be referenced from and does not affect the scope enclosing the *FunctionExpression*.

where a `FunctionExpression` is defined as:

> *FunctionExpression* : **function** *Identifier*<sub>opt</sub> ( *FormalParameterList*<sub>opt</sub> ) {*FunctionBody*}

Comment: I tried this in Firefox and Chrome I get 1undefined too... However logically the answer should be 1function?

Comment: @Vikram: If `f` was accessible in the calling context, then yes, it would be `1function`. Just move the expression outside of the condition, so that it gets evaluated as function declaration and use `if(f)` and you will see.